# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() not updating the collection in mongodb using NodeJS

Tags: mongoose

I am a fairly new developer trying to develop a simple CRUD application with help of API Endpoints using NodeJS, MongoDB and Mongoose. When using the findOneAndUpdate method of the Mongoose driver to update the documents I am not getting the correct results.

The collection is formed with help of mongoimport command by importing the CSV file. Consider that I have the following document.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("599c8da6b18e3117b09ea299"),
"MetaKey" : "lastWPSyncedStatus",
"MetaValue" : "Running"
```

}

Here the MetaKey is lastWPSyncedStatus and its corresponding value is going to Running.

All I need to do here is that when a "/test/client" endpoint is hit I want to update the **lastWPSyncedStatus to STOP**. The URL is submitted with PUT HTTP method for updates.

```
RosterOptions.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        'MetaKey' : 'lastWPSyncedStatus'

    },
    {
        $set:
            {
                'MetaValue': 'STOP'
            } 
    },
    {
        new: true

    },
    function(err,data){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(data);
        // console.log(data);
    }
)
```

I am trying to update the MetaValue to 'STOP' of the document that has the MetaKey as 'lastWPSyncedStatus'. I have tried submitting the query in the nodejs and it returns without any errors but the mongodb is not updated. Also when i had setup a debug for mongoose the following query is submitted to the mongoose.

```
Mongoose: rosterOptions.findOne({ MetaKey: 'lastWPSyncedStatus' }, { new: true, fields: {} })
```

And output is:

```
{
"_id": "599c8da6b18e3117b09ea299",
"MetaKey": "lastWPSyncedStatus",
"MetaValue": "Running"
```

}

I am not able to identify where the problem lies. I have also tried to use the update method but I get the following output.

```
{
"ok": 0,
"n": 0,
"nModified": 0
```

}

My documents are updated correctly when I try to run the function update() in the mongodb.

I referred to [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) and tried to implement it in a similar manner. I would be glad if someone could guide me through the problem.

Comment: Can you share the Mongoose Schema of `RosterOptions` collection?

Comment: Hey, @ryder I have fixed the problem correctly. I have made a mistake in defining the schema properly due to which I have faced this problem. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer to the question posted. I made a mistake in defining a schema properly due to which mongoose was not able to identify my collection correctly. I have fixed the issue by modifying the schema. Marking it as an answer.

Comment: I have been running around in circles, thank you sharing for this!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!